# How do I subscribe to an event using task expressions?

Tags: f#, event-handling, task

I have a function `doSomething : EventArgs -> Task<Unit>`, an event source `Source` and an event `Source.OnChanged`. How can I subscribe `doSomething` to `Source.OnChanged`? In C# we would use an async event handler but this doesn't seem possible in F#.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding events that return tasks and returning events in general. Problem is that when multiple event handlers are subscribed, all are called, but only last return value. This would mean that `await MyEvent.Invoke(foo, bar)` will wait only for last registered event handler and rest could still be executing or throw exception, which couldn't be processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```ml
let source = Source()
source.OnChanged.Add(
    doSomething
        >> Async.AwaitTask
        >> Async.StartImmediate)
```

Full example:

```ml
type Source() =

    let event = Event<int>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member _.OnChanged = event.Publish

    member _.Trigger(arg) = event.Trigger(arg)

let doSomething arg =
    task {
        printfn $"Doing something with {arg}"
    }

let source = Source()
source.OnChanged.Add(
    doSomething
        >> Async.AwaitTask
        >> Async.StartImmediate)

source.Trigger(0)
```

Output is:

```
Doing something with 0
```

See [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281990/f-asynchronous-event-handlers-for-wpf-similar-to-cs-async-and-await) for more details.